# Impossible to import mx.controls.Alert

Tags: apache-flex, popup, alert

I got a strange problem.
Just using Flash Builder 4.5 and trying to use the Alert Popup for some user messages.
But when i use it, it told me :

"Importation not found" (with a ? logo)

Here is the code :

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.CloseEvent;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you only included the Spark component set. Alert is only available in the MX component set. You need to include it as well in your project.

Right click on your project and choose **Properties**. Choose **Flex Build Path** from the left menu. You should see an option for **Component set**. Make sure to set it to **MX +  Spark** (or **MX only** if you don't need Spark).

Comment: I cannot see any Component Set option. When u say right click on my project, which file exactly ? Thanks

Comment: Right Click your Project ->Select Properties.Properties window will be opened.In the left pane of this window select Flex Build Path.In the right side you will ComponentSet option.

Answer (score 0):

Is your project a Flex Mobile Project? If so the mx components are not available....  There are crazy ways around this, but its pretty difficult